# C# Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime inkmanager

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I have created a new Universal App for C#.
In Windows 8.1 Runtime I have created a inkmanager which can draw on a canvas, Works fine!
Now I want to do the same for the phone(8.1), but these libraries are missing.
I have been looking on Google but to no avail. Has anybody found a solution for this problem?
Or do I have to go back to Silverlight 8.1?

**UPDATE**

The only thing left to do is having a webview with a javascript canvas to draw, it solved my problem...but it's not the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InkManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.inking.inkmanager.aspx) is currently not available for Windows Phone Store apps.

Comment: yes i know that, but is there something else to get around the problem? thx for the help :)

Comment: They want to piss us off!

Comment: Until there is no Windows Phone with a stylus/digitizer, I can understand that this APIs are missing.

Comment: The only thing left to do is having a webview with a javascript canvas to draw, it solved my problem...but it's not the best.

Comment: At which point is a HTML canvas better than a XAML canvas, like e.g. in [this example](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger)?